# How to customize Wordpress post navigation links default template in single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I customize post nav links default template in single.php. Is there any way to override the current navigation template? I have given my code here.

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        content-___.php            
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        the_post_navigation( array(
            'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' ,

            'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' ,

        ) );

    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: what do you want here? custom pagination ?

Comment: @dipmala exactly. I have html for the navigation. Either i want to implement the navlink in my custom html or  just customize the existing template.

Comment: Then you can directly change in template file

Comment: Where do I can find that? and isn't there any way to override the template?

Comment: You are already in then\me's template so you can change that directly.

Comment: How could I? Can you please provide a sample code, it would be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172983/discussion-between-sonu-sasankan-and-dipmala).